# Understanding of Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

*Definition.* A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open set if it is a union of open intervals.

Example: $(0,1)\cup (2,3)\cup (4,7)$ i.e., $A=${ $0<x<7$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$} is open.

*Proposition*. If $\mathcal{U}$ is set of open sets then $\bigcup\mathcal{U}$ is open.

**My question is**: Can you check my example? What is ''set of open sets'' mean Can you explain 'set of open sets'? Also, Can you give example ''set of open set''?

Comment: My example of set of open sets: Let $A=${ $2<x<3$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$}, $B=${ $4<y<5$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$}. So, $X=${$A,B$} is set of open sets, right?

Comment: @Arthur Must it be in the other set?

Comment: I should point that this is not the usual definition of an [open set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set). In $\mathbb{R}$, or, more generally, in a metric space $(M,d)$, the "standard topology" is the one where $A\subset M$ is open if $\forall a\in A \ \exists \varepsilon \gt 0$ such that $B(a,\varepsilon ) = \{ y: d(a,y)\lt \varepsilon \} \subset A$.

Comment: Your definition isn't the standar one, even with usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$, your "definition" is actually a theorem. On the other hand, "set of open sets" means a set whose elements are open sets. You could say instead "family of open sets" to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your example is indeed an open set, but you have analyzed it incorrectly: e.g. $x=1.5$ is not in $(0, 1)\cup (2, 3)\cup (4, 7)$. Do you see why?

A set of open sets is . . . a set of open sets. For example, the set of all open intervals. Or, the set $$\{(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 7)\}.$$ The union $\bigcup \mathcal{U}$ of a set $\mathcal{U}$ of open sets is just the set of all points which are in *some* set in $\mathcal{U}$. So, for example,

- The union of the set of all open sets is all of $\mathbb{R}$ (since every point is contained in some open set).
- The union of the set $\{(1, 3), (0, 2)\}$ is $(0, 3)$ (think about how the open sets $(1, 3)$ and $(0, 2)$ "overlap").

Does this make sense?

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I still have a question. Let $\mathcal{U}=${$(2,4)\cup (3,5), (5,7)\cup (7,9), (8,12)\cup (11,13)$} be set of open sets. For each $u\in\mathcal{U}$, let $I_{u}$ be set of open intervals. ,i.e., $I_{u}=${(2,4),(3,5), (5,7), (7,9), (8,12), (11,13)$}. Are my examples true?

Comment: Now, how can I write $\bigcup\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: @Kahler I don't understand what $I_u$ is. But $\bigcup\mathcal{U}$ is just the set of points in some element of $\mathcal{U}$. So $\bigcup\mathcal{U}$ is the union of the intervals $(2, 4), (3, 5), (5, 7), (7, 9), (8, 12), (11, 13)$; and this is just $(2, 5)\cup (5, 7)\cup (7, 13)$. Note that this is **not** $(2, 13)$: it doesn't contain $5$ or $7$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Note also that your $\mathcal{U}$ can be simplified: $(2, 4)\cup (3, 5)=(2, 5)$ and $(8, 12)\cup (11, 13)=(8, 13)$, so $\mathcal{U}$ can be more clearly written as $$\mathcal{U}=\{(2, 5), (5, 7)\cup (7, 9), (8, 13)\}.$$ (Do you see why $(5, 7)\cup (7, 9)\not=(5, 9)$?)